# Custom post type isn't working

Tags: custom-post-types, theme-development, functions, admin

I just built up a beta environment for testing my new Wordpress site.  I didn't migrate the database; I did my own installation again and ported over my theme (it's a simple theme) to my new instance.  Everything is working great, except for the one custom post type that I am using.

Here is the relevant code from `functions.php`:

```
function createCommunityPostType() {
    $args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'label' => 'Community',
            'capability_type' => 'community',
                'capabilities' => array(
                                'edit_post' => 'edit_community',
                                'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_communities',
                                'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_communities',
                                'edit_posts' => 'edit_communities',
                                'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_communities',

                                'delete_post' => 'delete_community',
                                'delete_posts' => 'delete_communities',
                                'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_communities',
                                'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_communities',
                                'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_communities',

                                'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_communities',
                                'read_post' => 'read_community',
                                'publish_posts' => 'publish_communities'
                ),
                'map_meta_cap' => true,
                'has_archive' => true
    );
    register_post_type('community', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'createCommunityPostType');
```

My custom post type isn't showing up in the menu and I can see that the capabilities don't exist (I'm using the members plugin to make that more visible).

I know the code is executing because I added some simple `print` statements before and after the call to `register_post_type`.  The print statements were part of the HTML response.

I can't figure out why this post type isn't working.  I have other methods in `functions.php` to handle stylesheets, scripts, some overrides for menus and sidebars and so on.  Those are all working fine.

**Edit**:

I changed to use default capabilities and the menu option is still not appearing:

```
function createCommunityPostType() {
    $args = array(
            'public' => true,
            'label' => 'Community',
            'capability_type' => 'community',
                'capabilities' => array(
                                'edit_post' => 'edit_posts',
                                'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_posts',
                                'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_posts',
                                'edit_posts' => 'edit_posts',
                                'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_posts',

                                'delete_post' => 'delete_posts',
                                'delete_posts' => 'delete_posts',
                                'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_posts',
                                'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_posts',
                                'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_posts',

                                'read_private_posts' => 'read',
                                'read_post' => 'read',
                                'publish_posts' => 'publish_posts'
                ),
            'map_meta_cap' => true,
                'has_archive' => true
    );
    register_post_type('community', $args );
}
add_action('init', 'createCommunityPostType');
```

I did however switch to using some very basic sample code from Wordpress and that Custom Post Type (CPT) appears:

```
function codex_custom_init() {
    $args = array( 'public' => true, 'label' => 'Books' );
    register_post_type( 'book', $args );
}
add_action( 'init', 'codex_custom_init' );
```

Comment: What **Plugins** do you have active? To eliminate possible issues with the **Members** Plugin, can you change the capabilities to reference core-defined capabilities, and report whether or not the CPT appears in the admin menu?

Comment: @ChipBennett - I am only using three plugins: Members, TinyMCE and WP LESS.  All three are enabled.  I updated my original post with the results of switching to default capabilities.

Comment: I think it might be a good idea to check what the register_post_type() function returns: $register_cpt_return = register_post_type('community', $args ); if( is_wp_error( $register_cpt_return ) ) wp_die( $register_cpt_return ); } Could you run this code and report the message you get?

Comment: I am not seeing any error message after adding this code to my method.

Comment: I would slowly build from a simple call to the more complex call, eliminating by process of elimination where the error lies.

Comment: "*I changed to use default capabilities and the menu option is still not appearing...*" I don't think you did, completely. Note this parameter: `'capability_type' => 'community'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One problem is that your `'capability_type'` parameter `'community'` doesn't match your `'capabilities'` array values.

[From the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments):

> capability_type
>
> (string or array) (optional) The string to use to build the read, edit, and delete capabilities. **May be passed as an array to allow for alternative plurals when using this argument as a base to construct the capabilities, e.g. array('story', 'stories').** By default the capability_type is used as a base to construct capabilities. It seems that `map_meta_cap` needs to be set to true, to make this work.

Your capability type is:

```
'capability_type' => 'community'
```

And note your `'capabilities'` array:

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'edit_post' => 'edit_community',
    'edit_private_posts' => 'edit_private_communities',
    'edit_published_posts' => 'edit_published_communities',
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_communities',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_communities',

    'delete_post' => 'delete_community',
    'delete_posts' => 'delete_communities',
    'delete_others_posts' => 'delete_others_communities',
    'delete_private_posts' => 'delete_private_communities',
    'delete_published_posts' => 'delete_published_communities',

    'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_communities',
    'read_post' => 'read_community',
    'publish_posts' => 'publish_communities'
),
```

Your capability type is **singular**, and your constructed capabilities are **plural**.

Try changing capability type to this:

```
'capability_type' => array( 'community', 'communities' )
```

Also, if you define `'capability_type'`, you *do not need* to define each capability explicitly. So, try **omitting the `'capabilities'` argument** entirely.

If your CPT doesn't appear after that, then the issue is likely due to your Members Plugin configuration:

1. Ensure you have properly defined your custom capabilities
2. Ensure that the current user has the capabilities referenced in the CPT.

Comment: Thanks for your help Chip.  I am still new to the Wordpress world and I forgot that the capabilities aren't automatically generated by Wordpress when setting up a CPT.  I needed to go in and create those capabilities.  Thanks!